# Use of Same method in Interface and Abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, extends, implements

I know this type question has been answered multiple times and it might get tagged as duplicate

I have a structure like this

```
public interface service{

    public void sayHello();
}

public abstract class AbstractService{

    public void sayHello(){
        System.out.println("Hello!!");
    }
}

public class MyService extends AbstractService implements service{

    public void sayHello(){
        super.sayHello();
    }
}
```

I know java does not allow multiple inheritance and we use interfaces to get away with that. But with this structure, I can't find a benefit/a business case on why I need to extend and implement? Because I have a concrete method in my abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a case where you have many, lets's say 10 w.l.g, extensions of the `AbstractService` and most of them (if not all) have the same behaviour in the method `sayHello`. You would need to implement this method in each class that implements the interface and you'll end up having a lot of duplcated code. This approach, in Java 7 or older, saves you in such cases.

Why did I say Java 7 or older? Well, since Java 8, interfaces have `default` methods implementation where you can actually provide a default implementation of the method, which you can override when you need to.